# TOTAL query using Magical Record on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

*(Forgive me as I'm new to Core Data and Magical Record)*

I want to execute a query using Magical Record that is equivalent to the following SQLite query:

`SELECT TOTAL(duration) AS duration FROM logbook`

My `Entry` model has a `duration` column that is an `NSDecimal`. Here's what I've tried:

`NSDecimal careerTotal = [[Entry MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:nil] decimalValue];`

With this, I get a crash that doesn't have any particular error message. Any MR wizards out there that can help? I looked and looked, but there aren't a lot of tutorials out there on MR. :)

Thanks!

---

**Update**

For what it's worth, I can get it to work with this:

`int careerTotal = [[Entry MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:nil] intValue];`

...but it obviously comes out rounded off like an int (28) when I need 1 decimal place (28.1). I suspect I'm having some kind of data type issue.

Comment: There may not be any error message, but you can still give us the type of the crash, and the code around it.

Comment: Here's my console output: http://d.pr/n/790Q

Comment: Alright, now are you getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, a SIGSTOP, or a SIGKILL?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS: http://d.pr/i/mjKW

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

It turns out I didn't need the second type indication and an `NSNumber` works.

`NSNumber *careerTotal = [Entry MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:nil];`

Thanks for your help, CodaFi.